# Break an array of keys and values into multiple arrays depending on varying lengths of the values

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a Python list in the following manner:

```
['Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'Although I wish could have a few more buttons',
 'Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'I am satisfied with the changes',
 'Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'I just received a call stating the issue has been resolved',
 'Comment by user12 [ 11/Apr/06 ]',
 'Nothing is responding', 
 'Please revert ASAP',
 'Comment by user50 [ 10/Apr/06 ]',
 'None of the tabs are loading any data.',
 'Comment by user54 [ 10/Apr/06 ]',
 'This seems very weird! I am not able to access any of the ',
 'changes that I made to this table yesterday. I wonder what is',
 'going on. Someone needs to have a look into this.',
 'Comment by user56 [ 09/Apr/06 ]',
 'Unable to access the shared drive.']
```

I want this table to be broken into lists like-

```
['Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'Although I wish could have a few more buttons']
['Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'I am satisfied with the changes']
['Comment by user14 [ 12/Apr/06 ]',
 'I just received a call stating the issue has been resolved']
['Comment by user12 [ 11/Apr/06 ]',
 'Nothing is responding']
['Comment by user12 [ 11/Apr/06 ]',
 'Nothing is responding', 
 'Please revert ASAP']
['Comment by user54 [ 10/Apr/06 ]',
 'This seems very weird! I am not able to access any of the ',
 'changes that I made to this table yesterday. I wonder what is',
 'going on. Someone needs to have a look into this.']
etc
```

Is it possible? I am unable to come up with a logic. The 'Comment by ...' is the key and the rows followed by it is the comment. These rows can be one or more and the 'Comment by ...' row can occur on the same day by the same user more than once and I was hoping if there is a way to get the value for each and every day. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
def is_header(text):
    return text.lower().startswith("comment by")

data_split = [] if is_header(data[0]) else [[]]

for item in data:
    if is_header(item):
        data_split.append([item])
    else:
        data_split[-1].append(item)
```